# Group files by their start name and find out how much space they use on linux

Tags: linux, diskspace

I have a bunch of files inside a directory on linux that look like this:

```
client1-aaaa.wav
client1-bbbb.wav
client2-aaaa.wav
client2-bbbb.wav
```

I would like to group them by the start string like clientX and see how much space each clients files use on that directory.

The result should be something like:

```
client1 - XXX Kb
client2 - XXX Kb
```

Any tips?

Comment: I would have used `du client1-*`, but apparently `du` does not allow regex parameters.

Comment: @fedorqui you are partially right, `du` does work but with some tricks, if you run `du client1-* -ch|grep total` you get a grand total for that client1's files. I guess that maybe using a for loop or something you might be able to go thru all client files.... anybody has a cleaner idea?